# Couldn't import a csv file into jupyter notebook

Tags: python, curl, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, data-science

I'm using Jupyter notebook of my anaconda environment with python 3.
I tried to curl the data from online and tried to import but the file wasn't found.

Code:

```
!curl -0 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jakevdp/data-USstates/master/state-population.csv

pop = pd.read_csv('state-population.csv')
```

Error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'state-population.csv' does not
> exist: b'state-population.csv'

Note: Curl worked fine.

```
state/region,ages,year,population
AL,under18,2012,1117489
AL,total,2012,4817528
AL,under18,2010,1130966
...
...
...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 57935  100 57935    0     0   129k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  129k
```

Comment: Maybe you can try using full file path instead of just the file name?

Comment: i used curl, how do i find the saved path ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find an alternative solution,
I did git clone all the .csv file to folder containing .ipynb and tried importing the .csv file, It worked !

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem you have questions about is more related to curl than loading a csv into Jupyter. You may get more help if you specify curl in your title.

Make sure you have Jupyter .ipynb file open on the same folder where curl saved the fetched csv file. Or pass the complete address of the path to the pd.read_csv function.

Comment: I did check the folder containing the .ipynb file, but no .csv file is present there !

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the full path of the file.

Comment: I don't know if the file is even downloaded, how will i give the full path ?

Comment: FIrst run the curl command in the terminal and download the file, then specify the full path of the file

Answer (score 0):

my friend,

You need to download the dataset first, using this command,

`!wget "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data"`

[image: Downloading Data into your current drive.]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


# reading the .data file using pandas
df = pd.read_csv('./auto-mpg.data', names=cols, na_values = "?",
                comment = '\t',
                sep= " ",
                skipinitialspace=True)
#making a copy of the dataframe
data = df.copy()
```

Upvote it if it is worked for you, Or give some comment if it doesn't work

Comment: My data is a .csv file in the location https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jakevdp/data-USstates/master/state-population.csv

Comment: **urlfile="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jakevdp/data-USstates/master/state-population.csv"

data = read_csv(url(urlfile))**
You can try this above code, It works.